# GithubElectron: A JavaScript error occured in the browser process

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, github, electron

I installed "electron-packager" using npm and executed the command

```
electron-packager . Johnston --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --version=0.36.0
```

And then I when I run the "Johnston.app", this error showed up (I didn't even see the main window)

> Uncaught Exception: Error: Cannot find module 'electron'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:332:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:282:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:361:17)
>       at require (module.js:380:17)
>       at Object. (/Users/David/Github/Johnston/Johnston-darwin-x64/Johnston.app/Contents/Resources/app/main.js:3:18)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:426:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:444:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:351:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:306:12)
>       at Object. (/Users/David/Github/Johnston/Johnston-darwin-x64/Johnston.app/Contents/Resources/atom.asar/browser/lib/init.js:104:10)

Is there any solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely has something to do with you having a different version of Electron installed on your machine that you are using to build with. In the folder for your app, run `electron --version` to get the version of electron that you have installed. Then, change the `--version=0.36.0` to use whatever version you have installed.

If that doesn't fix it, then you should try `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` on your project. This will remove you node modules and then reinstall them all. If that doesn't work, please comment here and I will try to help again.